# Add element to an array

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have a class `Person` and an object which is a `List<Person>`.
This list is XML-serialized. The result is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd... (etc)
  <Person>
    <Id>0</Id>
    <Name>Person 0</Name>
    <Birthday>2000-01-01T00:00:00</Birthday>
  </Person>
  <Person>
     ...
  </Person>
  <Person>
     ...
  </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

I want to add a new `Person` object to this List.

Using a `XmlSerializer<List<Person>>` I can Deserialize the complete XML to a `List<Person>` object, add my Person and Serialize it back to XML.

**This seems to me a waste of processing power!**

Is there a way I can add my Person without having to translate the XML text of all other person into Persons objects and translate them back to text?

I can use `XElement` to parse my XML to find my `ArrayOfPerson` and add one new `XElement` that contains my `Person` data. There are several answers here on SO that suggest this.

However, to create this `XElement` I have to enumerate the properties of the `Person`. get the values and add sub-elements to my `XElement`.

Is there some class of Method that can Create an XElement from an object, something like:

```
Person myPerson = ...
XElement xmlPerson = XElement.ToXml<Person>(myPerson);
```

Or do I have to write this myself?

Or maybe there is an even better method?

Comment: Why keep the XML in sync all the time? Why not just generate it, on demand, when you need it?

Comment: I haven't got the faintest Id what you mean. I have an XML file of a few thousand Persons. My class receives a new Person and needs to add it to the XML file. I'm not sure what the sync part is in this.

Comment: You add one. And you update the XML. Now you add another. And you update the XML. And so on. I am asking why you are updating the XML after each add? Just generate it once, when you need it, rather than after each add.

Comment: Of course there's a way to add it without deserializing the XML. You could serialize your single `Person` object to a `MemoryStream`. Then manually insert the result right before `</ArrayOfPerson>`.

Comment: mjwills: now I understand what you mean. My software is a service that receives once per day confirmation that our company delivered some information. For simplicity I called this a Person. In reality the informaitno has a much more complex structure. So Once a day I have to add one received "Person" to my array of "Persons"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XML LINQ:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        private static void Main()
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            reader.ReadLine(); //skip the unicode encoding in the ident

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
            XElement arrayOfPerson = doc.Descendants("ArrayOfPerson").FirstOrDefault();

            arrayOfPerson.Add(new XElement("Person"), new object[] {
                new XElement("Id", 0),
                new XElement("Name", "Person 0"),
                new XElement("Birthday", DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()),
            });
        }
    }
}
```